# ENCYRPTED partition-wide persistance in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, persistence

I am making a Ubuntu live boot USB for my own project, which contains many private coding, so I need to make my persistence partition encrypted. Just like the one in Kali Linux, LUKS and persistence preventing any information being stolen. However, I have no luck on both Google and forum at this moment.

Q&As:

Why don't you install Ubuntu in the USB directly? This USB is going to be used in many places like school computers, which is may not compatible greatly if I do a direct install, also It takes so much space for a direct one.

Why need encyrpted? Not just private codes, also something private like photos can also be stored there.

Why don't you use Kali? I am also a user of it but I want to separate those hacking files and hacking configuration from my own code.

Will be so happy if I can receive some help here. Ubuntu is truly wonderful if encrypted persistence exists.

P.S. already a thread open in [Ubuntu Forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2343322) but wish to get some help here. I try to inspect the source code of kali but not all part of it is open source!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the path of least resistance would be to use a regular live USB flash drive with persistence enabled, create a LUKS container and mount it when needed...

To create a LUKS container, here named Vault.dat, open it and format it `ext4`:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=Vault.dat bs=1M count=1024
cryptsetup luksFormat Vault.dat
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen Vault.dat Vault
sudo mkfs -L VAULT /dev/mapper/Vault
sudo cryptsetup luksClose Vault
```

To open the encrypted container, use it, then close it:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen Vault.dat Vault
sudo mount /dev/mapper/Vault /mnt
# ... the encrypted container is mounted on /mnt ...
# ... you can write, edit and read files from /mnt ...
# ... you may want to chown $USER /mnt ...
# ... close the container when you are done ...
sudo umount /mnt
sudo luksClose Vault
```

DigitalOcean provides a good tutorial, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-dm-crypt-to-create-an-encrypted-volume-on-an-ubuntu-vps.

Tested with `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` written to a USB flash drive by Universal USB Installer 1.9.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

I've been patching ubuntu livecds to add encrypted persistence for years now.  Unfortunately, Ubuntu doesn't accept my [patches](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1215504)...  My solution only adds encryption for the file persistence, not partition persistence (this could be done with GPT and a specially named partition, MBR might be more difficult).  I have a blog post [here](https://archimedesden.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/encrypted-persistent-ubuntu-livecd-16-10-redux/), that should work for most versions of ubuntu, and a [forum comment](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2343322&p=13605902#post13605902) with extra info.

Basically you need to patch the isos initrd to add the encryption and then repack the iso.  Next create the luks encrypted persistence file on the USB on a FAT32 filesystem (you might be able to use EXT if you want more than 2G of space).  I then make the USB bootable with grub2 and configure grub2 to loopback mount the iso and boot via the loopback.cfg grub config file.